# How to kill all running threads once some condition is met

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to create a process whereby I have multiple threads running, each running the same function with different parameters. The objective is to kill all threads once one of the first thread meets a certain condition. In my case each my case the function scrapes some messages from a specific url in a continuous loop and once a keyword is mentioned the loop should stop.

Here is the code:

```
def listen(channel_url):    
    global asset
    global stop_threads
    
    while True:
        
        text_msg = read_telegram3(channel_url)
        timestamp = datetime.now()
        print(f'Channel: {channel_url} \n {timestamp} : {text_msg} \n')
        announcement= [keyword for keyword in keywords if(keyword in text_msg)]
        
        if len(announcement) > 0:
            stop_threads = True
            
        if stop_threads:
            break
            
                
        # if stop_threads:
        #     break

announcement= []

t1 = threading.Thread(target=listen, args=([url]))
t1.start()
time.sleep(10)
t1.join()
```

The problem is the loop, only seems to execute once and not continuously until the condition is met as intended.

Comment: This question will be hard to answer, because we cannot reproduce: execution depends on reading your telegram channels. You would get more (and better) answers if you provide a [mre] using *fake data input* so that others can test and run the code. Having a loop in worker threads testing for a global condition is a common pattern so IMHO the problems is either in the implementation (but we cannot test...) or in the input data (but we do not have it...).

Comment: Throw in some more prints to see where the execution stops/hangs, what the content of announcement is, and so on.

Comment: Do you get an exception? Are you sure that `stop_threads` is defined? Are you sure that `len(announcement) <=0` in the first run?